# Parse the following JsOn with python3

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

Please help me to get gRecaptchaResponse key from the following json in python

```
{'errorId': 0, 'status': 'ready', 'solution': {'gRecaptchaResponse': '03030359652SF_JNFDjddfjkjDJFKLjfds+5d6sa5d+6S56C562CS+5sc9SC262jfdsjfJDF'}, 'cost': '0.112200', 'createTime': 1537281783, 'endTime': 1537281806, 'solveCount': 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
resp = {'errorId': 0, 'status': 'ready', 'solution': {'gRecaptchaResponse': '03030359652SF_JNFDjddfjkjDJFKLjfds+5d6sa5d+6S56C562CS+5sc9SC262jfdsjfJDF'}, 'cost': '0.112200', 'createTime': 1537281783, 'endTime': 1537281806, 'solveCount': 0}

#for key
print(list(resp['solution'].keys())[0])

#for value
print(resp['solution']['gRecaptchaResponse'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out:

```
json_data = {'errorId': 0, 'status': 'ready', 'solution': {'gRecaptchaResponse': '03030359652SF_JNFDjddfjkjDJFKLjfds+5d6sa5d+6S56C562CS+5sc9SC262jfdsjfJDF'}, 'cost': '0.112200', 'createTime': 1537281783, 'endTime': 1537281806, 'solveCount': 0}

g_key = json_data['solution']['gRecaptchaResponse']
```